# What are the different platforms for Qt's configure

Tags: qt, build, qt-creator

I'm trying to build Qt on Windows with the following command:

```
configure -static -opensource -no-webkit -no-qt3support -no-audio-backend -no-exceptions -no-opengl -no-phonon -phonon-backend
```

and I get this error:

```
Unable to detect the platform from environment. Use -platform command lineargument
```

However I don't know what are the different possible values for the "-platform" argument. I tried "win32" and "windows" but none of them are right. I can't find any reference that would list the possible values. Does anybody know what I need to put for Windows 7 (developing with Qt Creator)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open `mkspecs` folder inside qt dir. There you can see multiple folders. Names of this folders are values for `-platform` switch.

For example, you can use `win32-msvc`. `msvc` means using MS visual studio compiler for buiding qt.

Comment: Thanks, i have another question then. Is it possible to use win32-msvc even though I'm using Qt Creator to build my application?

Comment: Of course, you can. Qt creator is only IDE. P.S. You must have MS VS installed on your system before using `win32-msvc`.

Comment: @Laurent, but why you are trying to build Qt manually ? Did you consider installation of Qt binaries ?

Comment: You **do not** have to have VS installed. You can alternatively use Windows SDK.

Comment: it's because I need a static build of Qt and I couldn't find pre-compiled binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found on [this topic](http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_6607_0.html) in russian language.

You should try `-platform` with those arguments:

- win32-g++ (for mingw)
- win32-icc (for intel)
- win32-msvc (for visual studio)