# trying to compile Qt with command configure -static give me an error

Tags: windows, qt, compilation, compile-static

I am trying to compile Qt 5.4.2 on my windows 8 but it got this message:

[image]

What means: ***-plataform as line argument or set QMAKESPEC***

Comment: Mingw? Try `configure -static -platform win32-g++`, if VisualStudio, use `configure -static -platform win32-msvc` ... Note that the console did not say `--plataform` but `-plataform`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the different platforms for Qt's configure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211188/what-are-the-different-platforms-for-qts-configure)